# Protein diet meal help

Tags: diet, bodybuilding, protein, high-protein, meal-plan

I'm trying to add muscle (from weightlifting) whilst getting rid of fat (from long walks cardio). I've been advised to consume 300g of protein a day.

I usually have 3 meals (breakfast , lunch, dinner). I find it easiest to eat at dinner time because I'm not in rush to finish eating.

Also for lunch, I only have access to Sainsbury's and I can't eat meat at lunch and I can't have too much food because I wouldn't be able to finish it before lunch break finishes.

Given those constraints what would be a good  daily meal plan?

Comment: 300 g of protein? Are you taking steroids? This is some old school advice. Man, we all share the same planet. If everyone ate that much protein, humanity would die. Have some moderation. If you don't get paid for your muscles or your athleticism - that means unless you belong to a small fraction of exceptional individuals, there is a absolutely no evidence that taking more than something between 1.4 and 2g of protein per pound of lean body weight does anything.

Comment: @Mellow -- can you add you sex, height, and weight to your question? 300 g is likely very excessive. There's also little chance you'd be able to consume that in three meals.

Comment: Why can you not eat meat at lunchtime? Depending on the Sainsbury's you go to, their deli counter does a decent variety of cold meats